# My terminal shows an error of package.json not found while running yarn start command what should i do?

Tags: reactjs

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "C:\\Users\\Anjana Poudel\\Documents\\Javascript\\React.js\\Projects-react"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.


$ node -v
v12.18.3
$ npm -v
6.14.6
$ yarn -v
1.22.5
```

Comment: you seem to be in the folder projects-react. Are you sure you dont have to cd into the acutal app folder?

Comment: im not sure. do i need to? please tell

Comment: I would assume but I cannot tell you because I dont know how your directory structure looks like. If you use something like react, you should know some terminal basics. Maybe watch a video or two on this. Find out what `current directory` means and what impact it has on the commands you run.

Comment: @TheFool thanks it actually worked while typing command cd foldername and after running yarn start.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

You might have ran the command `yarn start` from the wrong folder. It might not have package.json

Usually when the new react app is installed into the system with `npx create-react-app my-app`, it creates the folder `my-app` in which all the react files reside. `cd my-app` command is required to run to access the files in the folder. Then `yarn start` or `npm start` will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to space in the path: "C:\Users\Anjana Poudel\Documents\Javascript\React.js\Projects-react".

https://github.com/redwoodjs/redwood/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

You must have used "create-react-app app_name" to create your application.
Try performing "cd app_name" to enter into your app folder and then use "yarn start". Happy Hacking! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing **"Couldn't find a package.json"**

> You need to change the path or directory . You need to go to the
> current project directory .

```
 You need to check the package.json file
 `script` whether it is working for you when
 you write `yarn start` or `yarn dev`.
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just installing yarn for the first time like me, create the general folder where you want to create the next app like **builds**. **cd (navigate)** into the created folder (builds in my case). Now run **npm install --global yarn** (make sure you are in the newly created folder). You can now create your app using yarn in that folder